# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement java (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for java

Tags: java, python, pycharm, python-import

I am trying to import java package to my project, so I installed JDK, after that I set the JAVA_HOME variable and now when I am trying to install the package I'm getting " Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement java (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for java"
how can I solve it? 
I use PyCharm and the last version of python

Answer (score 1):

The package you're looking for, although imported using `import java`, is called [`import-java`](https://pypi.org/project/import-java/) and can be installed using `pip install import-java`.